# I can not find the solution when it comes to CRISPY FORMS

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

IN MY DJANGO PROJECT I AM GETTING THIS EXCEPTION

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_formsmyapp'
```

I installed it, and added to the INSTALLED APPS as well as CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4', and double times reinstalled in venv and out of venv

Comment: IN MY INSTALLED APPS ALSO ADDED AS WELL AS CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

Comment: OTHER THAN THAT, DOUBLE TIMES REINSTALLED IN THE VENV AND OUT OF THE VENV BUT NOTHING CHANGED

Comment: Please don't type in all-caps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the symptoms, your `INSTALLED_APPS` has a missing comma that triggers [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation). My crystal ball says you have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # ...
  'crispy_forms'
  'myapp'
]
```

where you should have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # ...
  'crispy_forms',   # note the trailing comma
  'myapp',  # not a bad idea to have a trailing comma here too
]
```